# ionic 3 - how to trigger "choose file" from camera plugin getPicture method

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic-native

With ionic 3, how to automatically trigger click event on the "choose file button" from ionic camera plugin?

I am using this, but the "choose file" button is really ugly and i'd like to skip this useless step and directly open the image sources options

```
import {CameraOptions, Camera} from '@ionic-native/camera/ngx';

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then(imageData => {

        const base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;

        return base64Image;
    }, error => {

        console.log('CAMERA ERROR -> ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
```

The button is really ugly and useless:

[image]